# How to keep cucumber Scenario object alive?

Tags: java, cucumber

How can I create Scenario object in cucumber framework and keep alive through all test run?
**First Class:**

```
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.Scenario;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;

public class TestStepDefinitionOne {
    
    Scenario scenario;
    @Before
    public void keepScenario(Scenario scenario) {
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }

    Given("First step")
    public void first_step() {
        // Some code
        scenario.log("Some text");
    }

    Given("Second step")
    public void second_step() {
        // Some code
        scenario.log("Some text");
    }
}
```

**Second Class:**

```
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.Scenario;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;

public class TestStepDefinitionTwo {
    
    Scenario scenario;
    @Before
    public void keepScenario(Scenario scenario) {
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }

    Given("First step")
    public void first_step() {
        // Some code
        scenario.log("Some text");
    }

    Given("Second step")
    public void second_step() {
        // Some code
        scenario.log("Some text");
    }
}
```

If I create @Before method in each step definition class everything works fine.
**My question:** Is there any way to create Scenario object in one place (like Hooks class) and keep it alive through all test run?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @hfontanez I have a lot of api test scenarios, and in each step I need to attach request.json and response.json to report. That is why I need Scenario object alive.

Comment: No... you don't need to keep the scenario object alive to do that. All you need to do is save the json files somewhere for later retrieval. For example, you could save them in a database. If that is too much, you could save them in some data structure like a list or a map.

Comment: @hfontanez I understand how to save json file, but how can I attach it to report? Usually I'm using scenario.log() or scenario.attach(). Is there any other way?

Comment: what report are you using?

Comment: @hfontanez cucumber maven report

Comment: Are you referring to this? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting/5.6.1

Comment: @hfontanez yes!

Comment: I have never used that report before. But regardless, I don't see the point of what you are trying to do. Each scenario reports data related to it while it's executing. Once it is done, there is no need to hold to an executed scenario for "reporting" purposes. What you described makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @hfontanez I suspect that the issue is how to have a single reference to current scenario so that there would be no need to inject scenario object to every instance of glued class. Probably some static method like `Utils.getCurrentScenario()` that you could call from anywhere of your codebase.